# How to registerKeyBindings in Cinnamon development?

Tags: gnome, cinnamon

I recently take a look at Cinnamon Applets development. And I found some codes like this in `applet.js`:

```
const Meta = imports.gi.Meta;
```

And they used a lot of functions from `Meta`, like `Meta.keybindings_set_custom_handler`. However I cannot even found any document of this functions only to guess what it means. I checked [Cinnamon Document](http://developer.linuxmint.com/reference/2.6/cinnamon-tutorials/importer.html) and found that it may be some C binding javascript code. They use [GObject Introspection](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GObjectIntrospection). And I an new to this area. I want to know where can I check lists of functions in `gi.Meta`?

There is an example of key bindings from [exist applet](https://github.com/einverne/workspace-grid-cinnamon-applet/blob/master/workspace-grid%40hernejj/applet.js#L13), but I am still confused.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://developer.linuxmint.com/reference/2.6/cinnamon-tutorials/using-documentation.html): ***imports.gi.Meta*** refers to **Muffin**, while others (eg. imports.gi.Gio) are third-party (usually GNOME) libraries that are documented elsewhere.

If you do a search on **Muffin** you will see that there is a linuxmint / [muffin](https://github.com/linuxmint/muffin) repository in github.